# Transmit data to Java application(servlet) in body of GET request

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications, web-development-server

How can I process data that is transferred in the body of a GET-request using a servlet?

I use a small, hosted vServer (netcup), running Ubuntu 18.04 Server as OS and Tomcat 9.

To simulate the http requests I use Postman. In the code example below(its only the doGET-method) i realized a little program, that processes the incoming data "value1" from the query-string of the incoming GET-request. When i try to transmit the same parameter in the body of the message, i get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error
Type: Exception Report, Message: null
Description: The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented   
it from fulfilling it from fulfilling the request


java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
myServlet1.doGet(myServlet1.java:25)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

How do I have to modify the code to allow transmission via the GET-body? If i transmit the data with the querystring (for example) "http://localhost:8080...?value1=10" then it works fine.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/myServlet1")
public class myServlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public myServlet1() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

              String value1s= request.getParameter("value1");
              int a=Integer.parseInt(value1s); // 
              a=a+10;

              writer.println("<html>");
                  writer.println("<head><title>Hello World Servlet</title></head>");
                  writer.println("<body>");
                  writer.println("    <h1>Hello value from a Servlet!</h1>");
                  writer.println("<h1>transmitted value: " + a + "</h1>");      
                  writer.println("<body>");
                  writer.println("</html>");
                  writer.close();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);

    }
}
```

I am very grateful for every tip and hint!

Comment: Can you reopen this question please? I have edited the question to be more focused.

Comment: what error you got can you elaborate it more ?

Comment: "I get an error" is not quite enough focus to consider reopening. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide such an example.

Comment: HTTP spec tells that GET requests should ignore the body. So your servlet is working perfectly fine. You'd instead better adjust your client to be more HTTP spec compliant. Perhaps you want to use POST or PUT instead? They also support params in URI if that was the actual X part of your XY-problem.

Comment: I edited the Question the thrid time now and it is still closed. @moderator: will it be opened again one day?

Comment: Reopening isn't automatic - the votes take some time. But BalusC's comment might already give you a hint about a possible answer or cause for your problem. Next time, just give as much information and steps to reproduce right from the beginning to not cause a question to be closed in the first time. This is a voluntary effort, not a paid full-service-agency to answer your questions the moment you need them. In fact, stackoverflow strives to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers, more than a quick resource for anyone with a current problem.